# Checklist and tools for confirming a Macbook is working correctly

Tags: macbook-pro

Thinking about buying a used Apple laptop computer, and wondering if there are any manual checklist or tools for confirming an Apple laptop is working correctly via some sort of automated diagnostics.

I'm not concerned about the state of any software on the computer, and the best solution would be me just running the diagnostics on boot from a thumb-drive, since I'd like to avoid having to install software on a computer I would not own at the point it's being tested.

Also, it'd be nice if the diagnostics output a report and any data it was able to discover on the spec of the hardware present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use [Apple Hardware Test](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1509) and selecting the More Info button from the Apple menu > About This Mac to get all the info you need.